# HTML take image from camera

Tags: html, image, google-chrome

I have been trying to create a website where you will be or not be able to change your profile picture. I have tried using the video tag with the type of: "video/*; camera", but noting happened.

And I'm using the chrome browser.

Please help me

Comment: Where is your code? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I suggest you to read the following page. Hope it helps: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/